# How to implement dependency injection by asp.net core boilerplate framework in WebApi project

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

i implemented dependency injection by asp.net core boilerplate framework in web application project but when i want to implement dependency injection by this boilerplate in asp.net core **WebApi** project,in calling my webapimodule at program.cs, i got this error :

> Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' from assembly
>   'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  // this line return error
  AbpBootstrapper.Create<WebApiModule>().Initialize();
  //
  CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
 }
```

could you give me some samples about how to implement dependency injection by asp.net core boilerplate framework in WebApi project.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase` exists in `.NET Full Framework` (not `.NET CORE`)!

if your project is `.NET CORE`, check if you have a full framework package reference.

Answer (score 1):

.net core does not run the sys.web pipeline.  Hence you will not be able to use that api in .net core.

You can use IFormFiles for file upload.

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

// full path to file in temp location
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}

// process uploaded files
// Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

Refer this link for details -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, my webApiModule depends on **AbpWebApiModule** and it does not support in .NET Core